# Display 3 specific attributes on new products(with startdate)

Tags: php, magento

I have a home page that displays new products, so products that have a startdate. These are in a widget.
Problem is they only display things like name, price, picture...

I would like to show 3 attributes per product, so the user instantly sees some specs of the product and can then click further to see all the details.

For example, desktops should have Processor family, harddisk capacity etc.
Laptops should display screen size etc.

Is this possible? The problem is that they have different categories so just adding the 3 attributes to the template will cause problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For each product you could check if it is a member of a certain category and then check for and display attributes based on a list in an associative array.  Something like this:

```
$_productsCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

$cats = array(  // keys are category IDs
  1 => array('processor', 'disk', 'ram'),  // attribute codes
  2 => array('screen', 'weight', 'battery')
);

// loop product collection in widget
foreach ($_productsCollection as $_product) {
  // loop array of categories
  foreach ($cat as $cat_id => $attributes) {
    // loop array of attributes if the product is in this category
    if (in_array($cat_id, $_product->getAvailableInCategories())) {
      foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attr = $_product->getData($attribute)) {
          $resource = $_product->getResource();
          // markup and $helper to display image here
          echo $resource->getAttribute($attribute)->getStoreLabel().': '.$attr;
          // markup and getProductUrl() here, etc.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is not tested, but might give you an idea.  You would need to add in some code to handle cases where the product might be a member of multiple categories in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is indeed a solution but i would like to code it a little bit cleaner. Since everything needs to be hardcoded. I think the best way probably is to create a module with a extra option for displaying on new products.